# If we consider an atom as a system then what is its temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atomic-physics

An atom can be considered a SYSTEM of particles (electrons and nucleons) that are structured in a particular way and moving with some velocity(electrons). So can it be assigned a temperature? What kind of mathematical treatment can be applied?

EDIT: just for fun can someone please apply statistical mechanics to a "model" atom  and tell us the results.

Comment: Temperature is a macroscopic property.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace yes, of course it is.

Answer (score 5):

Temperature is defined as an average energy per atom/molecule/particle. Thus, it is a statistical property of systems with many atoms/molecules/particles. Defining a temperature for a single atom is thus statistically unfounded. Such attempts are indeed regularly made and result in sensational article headlines and "paradoxes"... because the temperature does not behave as it should :)

Comment: "Thus, it is a statistical property of systems with many atoms/molecules/particles.." the atom can also be considered to be a system of many **particles** . Either  there is a special assumption about those atoms when deriving temperature or the analysis can be applied to atoms as well. ".. because the temperature does not behave as it should " can you point to any resources? thnx

Comment: Temperature is a statistical concept, an average over many atoms. When you have only one atom, such averaging is impossible. The properties and the assumptions are explained in any statistical physics textbook. Indeed, the concept of tempreture is applicable only under the assumptions of statistical physics (many atoms, energy equilibration, ergodicity, etc.)

Comment: Temperature being average kinetic energy is only valid for classical mechanics. Atom is far from being a classical system.

Comment: @Ruslan Indeed. Still, for quantum systems temperature defines statistical distribution of many particles.

Comment: @Ruslan temperature is a measure of energy which quantum systems also have in some form or another. thus an atom should also have a temprerature.

Comment: @shashankshekharsingh it's not a measure of energy in general: the most general definition is via entropy. In its ground state, an atom's particles have nonzero mean kinetic energy, yet ground state is the lowest energy state possible for this system, so it's the state that it'll be in at absolute zero temperature.

Comment: @Ruslan at absolute zero there is no motion at ALL. is that incorrect ? that's another good question actually. what happens to the atom (its interiors) at absolute zero.

Comment: @shashankshekharsingh that's incorrect. There can't be "no motion at all" in bound quantum systems. They always have at least the [zero point energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy).

Comment: @Ruslan because of the uncertainity principle??? OK thanx

Comment: @shashankshekharsingh yes, but do read the article I've linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: @shashankshekharsingh dunno what the aether has to do with this

Answer (score 3):

If we consider the kinetic theory of gases, then atoms/molecules are effectively assumed to be small hard spheres with no description of what is inside them. They are very clearly particles and there is no question of an associated wave motion (classically) to each atom. In order to conduct experiments or describe real world effects of temperatures, this is an acceptable approximation of an atom (since an atom is not actually a hard sphere).

However, for subatomic particles, their quantum mechanical properties begin to play a role that cannot as easily be ignored. Thus, as is mentioned in a comment, the understanding behind calling elementary particles as particles is different from calling atoms or molecules as particles.

I am not aware of analyses that continue to do this at the subatomic level anyway, however this could be a possible starting point to sort of observe the unusual paradoxes that come up with newer definitions of temperature.

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/01/130104143516.htm

Comment: interesting link but useless as it is "popular" article. just a collection of random facts.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers already pointed out, temperature is meaningless for a single atom. This can be defined mathematicaly as follows.

Temperature is defined as proportional to the average CoM kinetic energy of the system (as defined by König's theorem). But what matters is the *standard deviation* around this average value: if it's too large, the average value doesn't represent the system faithfully, as particles have a high probability to have a kinetic energy very different from the average.

Typically, standard deviation for the kinetic energy for a system of $N$ atoms is proportional to $1/\sqrt{N}$. Therefore:

- For a single particle, this standard deviation is very large, making the average value meaningless: you can compute it, but it doesn't represent anything relevent.
- For a large collection of particles, it goes to zero, so almost all particles have a kinetic energy very close to the average value.

Only in the second case can you make anything physically useful with the average kinetic energy, for example define:
$$\langle K\rangle=\frac{3}{2}\,kT$$
which is a way to define absolute temperature.

Comment: Heavy elements can have on the order of a 100 electrons for a single atom. The question then is whether this is large enough to apply statistical physics.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion I'd say no. Years ago I ran some simulations on a somewhat similar question, and it needed orders of magnitude more particles before average values became statistically significant. But it was a classical simulation, not quantum, so…

Comment: Still though , can there be a temperature of an atom or not ,( yes/no or Maybe) ??

Comment: @shashankshekharsingh Please point out what isn't clear in my answer, I'll try to make it clearer.

Comment: @Miyase your answer states the already established facts. But what I am asking is whether you can consider an atom as a system of particles and thus have a defined temperature. Basically if a system of subatomic particles can have a temperature then surely an atom can have  a temperature. I just want to know whether that is true or not.

Comment: @shashankshekharsingh At this scale, the particles are purely quantum in nature, so they have no defined velocity, invalidating the notion of temperature. So it's not a matter of something being true or not, but a matter of 1) designing a new definition of temperature and 2) proving that it has any relevance. I've never heard of any such work.

Comment: @Miyase thanks a lot. This really shed some light on the problem.